# Two arrays using the same variable. 2nd and 3rd drop down dependent on first arrays completely different

Tags: javascript, dynamic-arrays

I wanted to create a second array that was dependent on the value from s1.value. If that Possible? can I have two arrays dependent one variable. I assumed that I could duplicate the function twice but that does not seem to work. can anyone help me?

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function populate(s1,s2){
     var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
     var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
     s2.innerHTML = "";
     if(s1.value == "Chevy"){
      var optionArray = ["|","camaro|Camaro","corvette|Corvette","impala|Impala"];
     } else if(s1.value == "Dodge"){
      var optionArray = ["|","avenger|Avenger","challenger|Challenger","charger|Charger"];
     } else if(s1.value == "Ford"){
      var optionArray = ["|","mustang|Mustang","shelby|Shelby"];
     }
     for(var option in optionArray){
      var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
      var newOption = document.createElement("option");
      newOption.value = pair[0];
      newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
      s2.options.add(newOption);
     }
    }
    function populate(s0){
        var s0 = document.getElementById(s0);
        s0.innerHTML="";
        if(s1.value == "Chevy"){
            var optionArray = ["|","johnny|Johnny" , "janey|Janey", "jimmy|Jimmy" , "kiesha|Kiesha"];
        }
        for(var option in optionArray){
            var par = optionArray[option].split("|");
            var newOption = document.createElement("option");
            newOption.value = pair[0];
            newoption.innerHTML = pair[1];
            s0.options.add(newOption);
        }
    }
      
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2>Choose Your Car</h2>
    <hr />
    Choose Car Make:
    <select id="slct1" name="slct1" onchange="populate(this.id,'slct2','slct0')">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="Chevy">Chevy</option>
      <option value="Dodge">Dodge</option>
      <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
    </select>
    <hr />
    Choose Car Model:
    <select id="slct2" name="slct2"></select>
    <hr />
    Choose who gets the car
    <select id="slct0" name="slct0"></select>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need the **Function populate(s0)**, try this :)

NOTE: you must make sure the variable spelling is correct as when i run your code, i found lots of variable with wrong spelling.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    
    <script>
    function populate(s1,s2,s0){
        var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
        var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
        s2.innerHTML = "";
        if(s1.value == "Chevy"){
            var optionArray = ["|","camaro|Camaro","corvette|Corvette","impala|Impala"];
        } else if(s1.value == "Dodge"){
            var optionArray = ["|","avenger|Avenger","challenger|Challenger","charger|Charger"];
        } else if(s1.value == "Ford"){
            var optionArray = ["|","mustang|Mustang","shelby|Shelby"];
        }
        for(var option in optionArray){
            var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
            var newOption = document.createElement("option");
            newOption.value = pair[0];
            newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
            s2.options.add(newOption);
        }
    
    
         var s0 = document.getElementById(s0);
        s0.innerHTML="";
        if(s1.value == "Chevy"){
            var optionArray = ["|","johnny|Johnny" , "janey|Janey", "jimmy|Jimmy" , "kiesha|Kiesha"];
        }else{
         var optionArray = ["|", "someValue|Some value"];
        }
        for(var option in optionArray){
            var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
            var newOption = document.createElement("option");
            newOption.value = pair[0];
            newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
            s0.options.add(newOption);
        }
    }
    
    /*
    Function populate(s0){
        var s0 = document.getElementById(s0);
        s0.innerHTML="";
        if(s1.value == "Chevy"){
            var optionArray = ["|","johnny|Johnny" , "janey|Janey", "jimmy|Jimmy" , "kiesha|Kiesha"];
        }
        for(var option in optionArray){
            var par = optionArray[option].split("|");
            var newOption = document.createElement("option");
            newOption.value = pair[0];
            newoption.innerHTML = pair[1];
            s0.options.add(newOption);
        }
    }
    */
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2>Choose Your Car</h2>
    <hr />
    Choose Car Make:
    <select id="slct1" name="slct1" onchange="populate(this.id,'slct2','slct0')">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="Chevy">Chevy</option>
      <option value="Dodge">Dodge</option>
      <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
    </select>
    <hr />
    Choose Car Model:
    <select id="slct2" name="slct2"></select>
    <hr />
    Choose who gets the car
    <select id="slct0" name="slct0"></select>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: @mcbrent hey I have altered the code above trying to dup several lines dependent on the from the first array and want the last array to be depdent on the first variable is it possible you can help me with the code?

Comment: As I understand, you want the 3rd dropdown(`select`) to be dependent on the first dropdown(`select`)?

Comment: @mcbrent  Yes I several (select) after the first that are that are duplicates and using the same array but the last select is not a dups but is dependent on the first select. I have the code if you would like to see it. it is similar to this code but I have been trying for weeks and can't fix it.